# python process  takes 100% CPU

Tags: python, cpu, consumption

I am trying to run python application and execute actions based on specified interval. Below code is consuming constantly 100% of CPU.

```
def action_print():

    print "hello there"

interval = 5
next_run = 0

while True:

    while next_run > time.time():
        pass

    next_run = time.time() + interval

    action_print()
```

I would like to avoid putting process to sleep as there will be more actions to execute at various intervals.

please advise

Comment: If you don't want to sleep one way or another, you'll burn CPU.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "there will be more actions to execute at various intervals"?

Comment: how can I make sure everything gets executed on-time while process is sleeping? I tried to use sleep however anything that is less than a second eats up the cpu.

Comment: Do you want this process to take 100% cpu?

Comment: @larsmans - i mean more actions are about to come not just print. whole problem is in intervals that are floats i.e. 3.5s, 4.73s etc.

Comment: @m1k3y02: compute the exact moments at which actions have to be undertaken, then sleep until that time.

Comment: @kasmanit - I want to avoid high cpu consumption while it is waiting for new action, which may come all of a sudden

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you know when the next run will be, you can simply use [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import time
interval = 5
next_run = 0
while True:
   time.sleep(max(0, next_run - time.time()))

   next_run = time.time() + interval
   action_print()
```

If you want other threads to be able to interrupt you, use an [event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) like this:

```
import time,threading
interval = 5
next_run = 0
interruptEvent = threading.Event()
while True:
   interruptEvent.wait(max(0, next_run - time.time()))
   interruptEvent.clear()

   next_run = time.time() + interval
   action_print()
```

Another thread can now call `interruptEvent.set()` to wake up yours.

In many cases, you will also want to use a [Lock](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to avoid [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) on shared data. Make sure to clear the event while you hold the lock.

You should also be aware that under cpython, only one thread can execute Python code. Therefore, if your program is CPU-bound over multiple threads and you're using cpython or pypy, you should substitute `threading` with [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you do not want to write time.sleep(interval) , but replacing 'pass' with time.sleep(0.1) will almost completely free up your CPU, and still allow you flexibility in the WHILE predicate.

Alternatively you could use a thread for each event you are scheduling and use time.sleep(interval) but this will still tie up your CPU.

Bottom line : your loop   WHILE  : PASS  is going round and round very fast consuming all your CPU.

Comment: a process on my OSX box running while True:time.sleep(0.1) shows in top as 0.0% cpu usage.